# Software License Project: how to avoid circular dependency

Tags: loops, circular-dependency

The title sounds like a bit unclear and I am not sure about the terminology. But my problem is: I am now implementing the license verification function of our software, which consists of several modules. For example, the function call is something like `License.IsModuleEnabled(m As Module)` (the code is in VB.NET)

Now the thing is, it is common for one module to require another module as a prerequisite, for example, for ModuleA to run, ModuleB must be enabled as well. So in `Module` class I have a public number called `RequiredModules` which is a list of `Module`. So the `IsModuleEnabled()` function would look something like this:

```
Public Function(m As Module)
   ...     
   For Each module In m.RequiredModules
       If Not IsModuleEnabled(module) Then Return False
   End For
   ...
End Function
```

The problem is obvious (but the solution is not to me): if ModuleA requires ModuleB, and ModuleB requires ModuleA, the function would go to a dead loop.

Those modules they are parallel to each other so I don't have a clue how to manage such a verification function. Our current solution is that only some "basic" modules can be listed in the `RequiredModules`, but for long term, to have all modules possible to appear in the list would be better.

Comment: Would you ever need ModuleA to be enabled without ModuleB being enabled or vice versa?

Comment: Could you not create a loop that iterates over the modules and its dependent modules, building a map of unique module names. If the module already exists in the map, skip it. When you reach the end of this loop, loop over your newly-created map and perform your boolean check on them then.

Comment: instead of returning true or false maybe return the name of the dependency module that way you can check to see if the module name is the name of the calling one.  You will have to return something other than true or false to stop the continual loop.

Comment: The problem you are describing is detecting cycles in a directed graph. Any algorithms textbook will have a solution. I do not have a textbook handy and don't remember it off of the top of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a set listing all modules for that the license is already verified, and check in this set before calling potentially redundant verification. If there is no value in the set, do verify and add the name of the verified module there.

Have another similar set to list modules for that verification has knowingly failed so we would not get into the endless loop in such situation as well.

This should work also if verifications happen in parallel as the knowledge keep accumulating in the set till will be sufficient to break the loops.